# How to insert a document with mgo and get the value returned

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

For the record, I'm learning Go. I'm trying to use and the mgo package and I'd like to insert a new document and return this newly created document to user (I'm trying to write a basic API). I've wrote the following code:

**EDIT: Here's the struct for the model:**

```
type Book struct {
  ISBN    string   `json:"isbn"`
  Title   string   `json:"title"`
  Authors []string `json:"authors"`
  Price   string   `json:"price"`
}

session := s.Copy()
defer session.Close()

var book Book
decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
err := decoder.Decode(&book)
if err != nil {
    ErrorWithJSON(w, "Incorrect body", http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

c := session.DB("store").C("books")

info, err := c.Upsert(nil, book)

if err != nil {
    ErrorWithJSON(w, "Database error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
log.Println("Failed insert book: ", err)
    return
}

respBody, err := json.MarshalIndent(info, "", "  ")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

ResponseWithJSON(w, respBody, http.StatusOK)
```

Please note that Book is a struct I have created earlier. The above code does work but what it returns is the upsert result like so:

```
{
    "Updated": 1,
    "Removed": 0,
    "Matched": 1,
    "UpsertedId": null
}
```

Which is not the recently created object. How can I get the the recently created object to return as a response (please note that ideally I'd like the confirmation that the document was successfully inserted. I have seen other questions where the ID is generated beforehand but for what I've seen it doesn't confirm that the document was created was it?)

Comment: Query the object back out after you upsert it.

Comment: But where's the ID to query it back?

Comment: In your object. This is clearly an update of an existing object based on your quoted output, which means you already have the ID.

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to insert for the first. Based on the documentation I've found so far, the `Insert` does not provide the ID either, so it was suggested to the Upsert method instead

Comment: The upsert result implies you're updating an existing document.

Comment: Consider providing the code for the struct as well. Does your struct have the ``bson:"_id"``tag?

Comment: I have tried using the Insert also, but I've run into the same problem where I couldn't get the ID of the document afterwards. After searching it was suggested to Upsert instead. I have added the struct and no, there's no ID tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's clear the concepts first. In MongoDB, each document must have an `_id` property which acts as its unique document identifier inside a collection. Either you provide the value of this `_id` or it is assigned automatically by MongoDB.

So it would be ideal (or it's strongly recommended) for your model types to include a field for the `_id` document identifier. Since we're talking about books here, books already have a unique identifier called ISBN, which you may opt to use as the value of the `_id` field.

The mapping between MongoDB fields and Go struct fields must be specified using the `bson` tag (not `json`). So you should provide `bson` tag values along with `json` tags.

So change your model to:

```
type Book struct {
  ISBN    string   `json:"isbn" bson:"_id"`
  Title   string   `json:"title" bson:"title"`
  Authors []string `json:"authors" bson:"authors"`
  Price   string   `json:"price" bson:"price"`
}
```

If you want to insert a new document (a new book), you should always use [`Collection.Insert()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Insert).

And what will be the ID of the newly inserted document? The field you set to the `Book.ISBN` field as we declared it to be the document ID with the `bson:"_id"` tag.

You should only use [`Collection.Upsert()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Upsert) if you are not sure whether the document already exists, but either way you want it to be the document you have at hand. `Collection.Upsert()` will try to find a document to update, and if one is found, that will be updated. If no document is found, then an insert operation will be performed. The first parameter is the selector to find the document to be updated. Since you passed `nil`, that means any document may qualify, so one will be selected "randomly". So if you already have books saved, any may get selected and get overwritten. This is certainly not want you want.

Since now the ISBN is the ID, you should specify a selector that filters by ISBN, like this:

```
info, err := c.Upsert(bson.M{"_id": book.ISBN}, book)
```

Or since we're filtering by ID, use the more convenient [`Collection.UpsertId()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.UpsertId):

```
info, err := c.UpsertId(book.ISBN, book)
```

If you want to update an existing document, for that you may use [`Collection.Update()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Update). This is similar to `Collection.Upsert()`, but the difference is that if no documents match the selector, an insert will not be performed. Updating a document matched by ID can also be done with the more convenient [`Collection.UpdateId()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.UpdateId) (which is analogue to `Collection.UpsertId()`).

For other documents which do not have a unique identifier naturally (like books having ISBN), you may use generated IDs. The `mgo` library provides the [`bson.NewObjectId()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#NewObjectId) function for such purpose, which returns you a value of type [`bson.ObjectId`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#ObjectId). When saving new documents with `Collection.Insert()`, you can acquire a new unique ID with `bson.NewObjectId()` and assign it to the struct field that is mapped to the MongoDB `_id` property. If the insert succeeds, you can be sure the document's ID is what you just set before calling `Collection.Insert()`. This ID generation is designed to work even in a distributed environment, so it will generate unique IDs even if 2 of your nodes attempt to generate an ID at the same time.

So for example if you don't have the ISBN for a book when saving it, then you must have a separate, designated ID field in your `Book` type, for example:

```
type Book struct {
  ID      bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
  ISBN    string        `json:"isbn" bson:"isbn"`
  Title   string        `json:"title" bson:"title"`
  Authors []string      `json:"authors" bson:"authors"`
  Price   string        `json:"price" bson:"price"`
}
```

And when saving a new book:

```
var book Book
// Fill what you have about the book
book.ID = bson.NewObjectId()

c := session.DB("store").C("books")
err = c.Insert(book)
// check error
// If no error, you can refer to this document via book.ID
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I'm still struggling to get it to work. I'm trying to use Insert as you suggest, but the document is created without a proper ID (ISBN) and I still don't get the document back after its creation. Would you be able to provide an example based on the code I've provided?

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK If you don't have the ISBN when saving the book, then you must use a generated ID as the document ID. See the last section of my answer. You set the ID prior to saving, and if the insertion succeeds, the ID will be exactly what you set prior to calling `Insert()`.

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK Added example how you can handle if ISBN is not always known.

Comment: I'm getting `cannot use bson.NewObjectId() (type bson.ObjectId) as type string in assignment` when trying to use `book.ID = bson.NewObjectId()`. Any idea why?

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK Because if you check my example, `Book.ID` is of type `bson.ObjectId` not `string`. Fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

Banged my head for a while on this.

```
info, err := c.Upsert(nil, book)
```

The `nil` selector for the upsert will match everything so if your collection is empty the selector won't match and all will be fine, the info object will contain the ObjectId in the UpsertedId field, but on every following upsert with nil selector the collection will have records and the nil selector for the upsert will match, therefore it won't return you the UpsertedId and you will be updating the first matched record.

**You could use never matching selector** for the upsert (which was my solution), but note that this way you will only insert and get the inserted ObjectId and never update a record.

You can checkout the following test:

```
func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    foo := struct {
        Bar string `bson:"bar"`
    }{
        Bar: "barrr",
    }

    session, _ := mgo.DialWithInfo(&mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs: []string{"127.0.0.1:27017"},
    })

    coll := session.DB("foo").C("bar")
    coll.DropCollection()

    info, _ := coll.Upsert(nil, foo) // will insert
    count, _ := coll.Count()
    fmt.Printf("%+v, collecton records:%v\n", info, count) // &{Updated:0 Removed:0 Matched:0 UpsertedId:ObjectIdHex("5c35e8ee1f5b80c932b44afb")}, collection records:1

    info, _ = coll.Upsert(bson.M{}, foo) // will update
    count, _ = coll.Count()
    fmt.Printf("%+v, collecton records:%v\n", info, count) // &{Updated:1 Removed:0 Matched:1 UpsertedId:<nil>}, collection records:1

    info, _ = coll.Upsert(bson.M{"nonsense": -1}, foo) // will insert duplicate record (due to the selector that will never match anything)
    count, _ = coll.Count()
    fmt.Printf("%+v, collecton records:%v\n", info, count) // &{Updated:0 Removed:0 Matched:0 UpsertedId:ObjectIdHex("5c35ea2a1f5b80c932b44b1d")}, collection records:2

    foo.Bar = "baz"
    info, _ = coll.Upsert(nil, foo) // will update the first matched (since the selector matches everything)
    count, _ = coll.Count()
    fmt.Printf("%+v, collecton records:%v\n", info, count)

    // after the test the collection will have the following records
    //> use foo
    //> db.bar.find()
    //{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c35ebf41f5b80c932b44b81"), "bar" : "baz" } // the first matched on the last update with nil selector
    //{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c35ebf41f5b80c932b44b86"), "bar" : "barrr" } // the duplicated record with the selector that never matches anything

}
```

**EDIT:** Note that you should have an index on the never matching field, or your insert query will take too long if you have many records, because the upsert on not indexed filed will scan all the documents in the collection.